# How to provide .ini file for wirelesshost.ned in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm working on a project where I need to compare the results on ieee802.15.04 with ieee8021506 using OMNeT++. I'm using OMNeT++ 5.4.1 along with INET 4.1, but I'm unable to load INET into OMNeT++ because of a few errors.

Could anyone guide me how to import inet into OMNeT++ and also how tp interface wirelessnode with ieee8021504?

Comment: To be able to help you we need more information about the error.

Comment: no such parameters are used
path not found
unused paramters